Create HTML table from array of Objects in Power Automate
I have a variable ObjectArrayItems that is an array of objects in Power Automate that looks like this:
[
  {
    "Name": "Date",
    "Value": "2024-10-11"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Time",
    "Value": "10-24-48"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Desc",
    "Value": "SSL VPN login fail"
  },
  {
    "Name": "IPAddress",
    "Value": "74.119.194.131"
  },
  {
    "Name": "User",
    "Value": "msi"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Group",
    "Value": "VPN-USERS-Epicor"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Msg",
    "Value": "SSL user failed to logged in"
  },
  {
    "Name": "",
    "Value": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "Date",
    "Value": "2024-10-11"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Time",
    "Value": "10-24-40"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Desc",
    "Value": "SSL VPN login fail"
  },
  {
    "Name": "IPAddress",
    "Value": "91.132.133.118"
  },
  {
    "Name": "User",
    "Value": "msi"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Group",
    "Value": "VPN-USERS-Epicor"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Msg",
    "Value": "SSL user failed to logged in"
  }
]

I am trying to get it into an email as an HTML table that will look like this:



Date
Time
Desc
IPAddress
User
Group
Msg




10/11/2024
10-24-48
SSL VPN login fail
74.119.194.131
msi
VPN-USERS-Epicor
SSL user failed to logged in


10/11/2024
10-24-40
SSL VPN login fail
91.132.133.118
msi
VPN-USERS-Epicor
SSL user failed to logged in



What I've ended up getting is something that looks like this instead:



Name
Value




Date
2024-10-11


Time
09-24-24


Desc
SSL VPN login fail


IPAddress
194.4.48.122


User
mikrotik


Group
VPN-USERS-Epicor


Msg
SSL user failed to logged in


Date
2024-10-11


Time
09-23-54


Desc
SSL VPN login fail


IPAddress
109.120.137.38


User
fortinet


Group
VPN-USERS-Epicor


Msg
SSL user failed to logged in



Or like this:



Date
Time
Desc
IP Address
User
Group
Message



With no values in the table.

Here is what I've tried:
Create HTML table with the from being my variable from above
"from": "@variables('ObjectArrayItems')"
That gave me the long table with Name and Value as the headers.
Then I tried this:
Create HTML table, same From as above, but then I selected the columns with something like this:
{
    "header": "Date",
    "value": "@variables('ObjectArrayItems')?['Date']"
},
{
    "header": "Time",
    "value": "@variables('ObjectArrayItems')?['Time']"
},
{
    "header": "Desc",
    "value": "@variables('ObjectArrayItems')?['Desc']"
},
{
    "header": "IP Address",
    "value": "@variables('ObjectArrayItems')?['IPAddress']"
},
{
    "header": "User",
    "value": "@variables('ObjectArrayItems')?['User']"
},
{
    "header": "Group",
    "value": "@variables('ObjectArrayItems')?['Group']"
},
{
    "header": "Message",
    "value": "@variables('ObjectArrayItems')?['Msg']"
}

This gives me an error saying

The execution of template action 'Create_HTML_table_1' failed. The column values could not be evaluated: 'The template language expression 'variables('ObjectArrayItems')?['Date']' cannot be evaluated because property 'Date' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

I'm certain there is a simple way to do this, but I've not been able to figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Note for email purposes, the one with two columns will work on mobiles, so it might not be a bad option!

Your problem is, each array item is a property and value, you need all of the properties and values grouped into a single object and created as items within another array.
To achieve that, you need to do the following ...
Part 1

Initialize Original Data
This is the data you provided in your question entered into a variable of type Array ...
[
  {
    "Name": "Date",
    "Value": "2024-10-11"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Time",
    "Value": "10-24-48"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Desc",
    "Value": "SSL VPN login fail"
  },
  {
    "Name": "IPAddress",
    "Value": "74.119.194.131"
  },
  {
    "Name": "User",
    "Value": "msi"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Group",
    "Value": "VPN-USERS-Epicor"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Msg",
    "Value": "SSL user failed to logged in"
  },
  {
    "Name": "",
    "Value": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "Date",
    "Value": "2024-10-11"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Time",
    "Value": "10-24-40"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Desc",
    "Value": "SSL VPN login fail"
  },
  {
    "Name": "IPAddress",
    "Value": "91.132.133.118"
  },
  {
    "Name": "User",
    "Value": "msi"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Group",
    "Value": "VPN-USERS-Epicor"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Msg",
    "Value": "SSL user failed to logged in"
  }
]

Filter Out Blank Properties
I noticed you had a break in the data where there was a blank property.  To remove that, I used a Filter array operation with the following expression ...

That expression at the item level is ...
length(coalesce(item()?['Name'], ''))

Initialize Object Array
Initialize a variable of type Array.  This will store the transformed array that will be used to create the HTML table.
Initialize Object
Initialize a variable of type Object.  For every new item we create with all properties, this will be that object.
Part 2

From here, we're going to loop through your data and create each object that contains each property per larger item.
The Apply to each is working off the result from the filtered data ...
body('Filter_Out_Blank_Properties')

If Property EQ Date
Date is your first property so in the condition, we need to check for that each time and act on it accordingly.

First we need to make sure that the Object variable isn't equal to NULL.  On the first iteration, it will be because it hasn't been built yet.
The second AND condition is ...
toUpper(item()['Name'])

... this checks to see if the current property is equal to Date.  If it is and the first condition is satisfied then we're starting a new object, so, append the existing object to the Object Array variable.  That's what the next step does.
Append To Object Array
It appends the Object variable to the resulting array.  The expression is ...
variables('Object')

Reset Object
This is a Set variable operation and resets the Object variable back to nothing, not null, just a blank object.  Set the value to ...
{}

Compose Add Property To Object
Outside of the condition, we now want to use a Compose operation to add the current property with its associated value to the Object variable.  To do that, this is the expression ...
addProperty(coalesce(variables('Object'), json('{}')), item()['Name'], item()['Value'])

Set Object
We now want to set the Object variable to be the output of the previous step.  The reason why we need the previous step and we don't just use addProperty() in a single step to set the variable is because it won't let you, you'll get an error.  This is the expression ...
outputs('Compose_Add_Property_To_Object')

Part 3

This is where we'll create the HTML table.
Append To Object Array (Last)
This step seems a bit weird but it's doing the same thing as the previously named Append To Object Array step.  It's the exact same thing.  We need it because when we processed the last property and added it to the object, we never loop around again like we do in the Apply to each operation section, so we need to add that very last object to the final array.  Without this, we'll miss one of the items.
So now overall, the Object Array variable will look like this ...
[
  {
    "Date": "2024-10-11",
    "Time": "10-24-48",
    "Desc": "SSL VPN login fail",
    "IPAddress": "74.119.194.131",
    "User": "msi",
    "Group": "VPN-USERS-Epicor",
    "Msg": "SSL user failed to logged in"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2024-10-11",
    "Time": "10-24-40",
    "Desc": "SSL VPN login fail",
    "IPAddress": "91.132.133.118",
    "User": "msi",
    "Group": "VPN-USERS-Epicor",
    "Msg": "SSL user failed to logged in"
  }
]

... THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED!!!
Create HTML Table
With that data, now you can create your HTML table.

This is the result ...
<table><thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Desc</th><th>IPAddress</th><th>User</th><th>Group</th><th>Msg</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>2024-10-11</td><td>10-24-48</td><td>SSL VPN login fail</td><td>74.119.194.131</td><td>msi</td><td>VPN-USERS-Epicor</td><td>SSL user failed to logged in</td></tr><tr><td>2024-10-11</td><td>10-24-40</td><td>SSL VPN login fail</td><td>91.132.133.118</td><td>msi</td><td>VPN-USERS-Epicor</td><td>SSL user failed to logged in</td></tr></tbody></table>


It took some work, but this did lead me to the answer that I needed. I have been able to get it formatted and setup for going into the email I needed it. Thank you for the help!

Yes, the answer took some work as well.  You’re welcome.
